# How can I remove identical (but negative) rows that are also in some days of each other from a SELECT on a table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with two fields: `date` and `value`.  `date` is of type date, and `value` is decimal(10,2).

There are "pairs" of rows (non-consecutive) whose values are of equal magnitude but opposite sign, within 7 days of each other.

```
date        value
...
2020-06-20  123.45
...
2020-06-25  -123.45
...
```

The above is a "pair" because they are negatives of each other and their dates are within 7 days of each other.  There may be any number of intervening rows.  There may be any number of pairs in the table.  Pairs of differing values may overlap 7 day periods.  For simplicity assume there are no other equal-value rows also with 7 days (ie, no triples).

I'm trying to find a SELECT statement that gives me all the table's rows EXCEPT "pairs".  Could someone please help?

Comment: Which version of MySQL and what engine are you using?  Could you provide more detail, I'm a little confused by "Pairs of differing values may overlap 7 day periods"?  Also provide the relevant key information for the table.

Comment: @bbaird by overlapping I mean in a table sorted by `date` one pair may exist within another pair, or one pair may include one member of another pair.  I wasn't sure if this would influence the query.  Basically assume nothing about the dates or values.  I'm running MySQL 5.6.  Thanks for mentioning "key".  I checked my table - duh - I was indexing neither column.  Added indexes for both columns and now the query runs in a few seconds.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM TABLE t2
                   WHERE t2.`value` = -t1.`value`
                     AND t2.`date` BETWEEN t1.`date` - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                                       AND t1.`date` + INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

Comment: Thanks @Akina.  Is the size of this query quadratic?  My table has nearly 10,000 rows and I think my server is killing the query after 30 seconds.  Can any efficiencies be had?

Comment: @Scott No, it looks like N*log(N). If the index by `(value, date)` (or in backward order - I cannot say what is more useful on your data) exists.